# How to align center then align left in table?

Tags: tables, spacing

How can I align my text in the table center then align it with the letter "M" ? Like the below it is right aligned but  I want it center-right aligned. How ?

[image]

Like below, the text is center aligned with M.

[image]

Comment: hard to say without a MWE. And I actually don't understand what you're asking

Comment: What does the M stand for?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I have updated my post

Comment: what is "center-right aligned", btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that is the first image the one you want to replicate, here's a MWE.
You can override the column alignment for a given cell by using `\multicolumn` for a single column (see also the last line - I added it to make it more clear).

In the first image you posted, the first cell from the top seems to be centered. This is obtained with `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\# Params}`.
The remaining ones appear to be simply right-aligned.
Since the content of every cell ends with an `M` (millions?), everything looks like to be aligned with the `M`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\# Params} \\
    \hline
    2.8M\\
    15.4M\\
    38.7M\\
    \hline
    2.9M\\
    62M\\
    12.9M\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{x} \\ % to prove that you can override the column alignment
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A better looking result can be achieved with the help of `siunitx`, assuming that `M` is a unit or a *Mega* prefix.
The package allows to define the `S` and `s` type of column.
You can play with the unit alignment with the `table-unit-alignment` key, that accepts values such as `left`, `right' or`center`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
{|S[table-format=2.1]@{\,}s[table-unit-alignment = center]|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Parameters} \\
    \hline
    2.8  & \mega \\
    15.4 & \mega \\
    38.7 & \mega \\ \hline
    2.9  & \mega \\
    62   & \mega \\
    12.9 & \mega \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! But what if I want to shift the entries with M slightly to the left and still have them aligned? Do I manually use \ ?

Comment: see the edit I just made. Basically the length of the word `Parameters` is driving the width of the table, and -therefore- how the cell contents look when aligned according to the column definition

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that I've understood your objective correctly, as the layouts in the two screenshots you've posted seem to be in direct conflict with each other. I've interpreted it as follows: (a) the numbers should be aligned on their decimal markers, (b) the `M` letters should be aligned, and (c) the number/`M` combinations should be centered horizontally within the column.

If this interpretation is correct, the following solution, which employs the `S` column type provided by the `siunitx` package, may be of relevance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=3.1,table-space-text-post={M}]|}
\hline
{\# Params}\\
\hline
15.4M\\ 2.8M\\ 388.7M\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd accept this answer rather than the  mine, myself! :) (+1)

Comment: thank you that looks easier to interpret